# Can I call a View's setWidth() using dip?

Tags: android, xml, layout

I am currently converting an XML layout to java code. I want to replicate exactly what I have but I cannot find several functions to set a View's attribute.

```
        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:weightSum="2">
            <TextView
                android:text="@string/parameters_insensitive_trip"
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center" />

            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/insensitiveTripSpinner"
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:prompt="@string/spinner_insensitive_trip"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center" />
        </TableRow>
```

using match_parent never works for setHeight() or setWidth(), using 0dip never works either, and I cannot find anything having to do with the weight of the Views.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: You should be using Table LayoutParams when constructing your views from code

Comment: Thanks. That doesn't seem to answer anything having to do with weight/gravity though. I am looking here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TableLayout.LayoutParams.html. I also still cannot use `0dip` only `match_parent` or `wrap_content`.

Comment: TableLayout.LayoutParams(int w, int h, float initWeight)  ?? Pass 0 to whichever you want to be 0dip

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking at the right layout class, the TableLayout.LayoutParams is derived from LinearLayout.LayoutParams so it has the weight and gravity fields, you can simply set them.

As for dip, you can call TypedValue.applyDimension to convert the desired dip value to pixels.